# making text appear after an image instead of over it

Tags: php, fpdf

```
<?php
include('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World',60,30,90,0,'PNG');
//$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Printing line number $i",0,1);
$pdf->Output();
```

The "printing line number x" text appears over the image - not below it. Any ideas how I can make it appear after the image? The commented out `$pdf->Ln()` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$pdf->SetX()`, `SetY()` or `SetXY()` to move the 'cursor' position. You can use `GetY()` to get the current vertical position and use `SetY()` to add the image height to that.